# Pass variable value outside out a loop

Tags: javascript

I know that probably would be the dumbest question to ask, but its a desperate attempt from a UI guy to do something... i have getting some values from a json file, and then i am passing those values to plot a graph using jflot.

//Script

```
function plot4() {
    $.getJSON("wc.json",function(data){
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
            var wc = data.title;
            alert(wc);
        });
    });

    function drawPlot() {
        alert(wc);
        // function which draws plot using jFlot using a huge dataset
    }
}
```

Is it okay that i wrap the getjson file outside the drawPlot function ??.. pls advice

Comment: Just FYI: I removed the `jQuery` and `JSON` tags as the spirit of this question centers around basic Javascript usage; jQuery & JSON are irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you declare `wc` (via `var wc`) to be in the scope of the "each" block.

To do what you want, you need to either:

1. move `wc` out to the scope containing both functions

   ```
   function plot4() {
       var wc;
       $.getJSON("wc.json",function(data){
           $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
               wc = data.title;
   ```
2. Or, if you actually wish to call `drawPlot` from your `each` loop (you don't seem to be calling it all!), pass `wc` as a parameter to it

   ```
   // ... some other code 
         var wc = data.title;
         drawPlot(wc);
   // ... some other code 

   function drawPlot(wc) {
       alert(wc);
      // function which draws plot using jFlot using a huge dataset
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with parameters?

```
function plot4() {
    $.getJSON("wc.json",function(data){
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
            var wc = data.title;
            drawPlot(wc);
        });
    });

    function drawPlot(wc) {
        // function which draws plot using jFlot using a huge dataset
    }
}
```

...or:

```
function plot4() {
    $.getJSON("wc.json",function(data){
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
            var wc = data.title;
            drawPlot(wc);
        });
    });
}

function drawPlot(wc) {
    // function which draws plot using jFlot using a huge dataset
}
```